# setSupportActionBar( ) is not working in android studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-intent, crash, toolbar

I'm trying to create a custom Toolbar on my Activity but at the time I launch the app it crashes
The code which I written for setSupportActionBar is below:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Its asking for creating method of setSupportActionBar and below error is coming out

D:\AndriodSDK\LcitNewDemo\app\src\main\java\com\lcit\lcitnewdemo\SetActivity.java:23: error: incompatible types: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

When I try to create method of setSupportActionBar(), its showing this error in logcat which I have mention in below answer

Comment: Can you share your logs from logcat of the time when app crashes

Comment: Please provide the crash logs.

Comment: D:\AndriodSDK\LcitNewDemo\app\src\main\java\com\lcit\lcitnewdemo\SetActivity.java:23: error: incompatible types: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);  Its asking for creating method.

Comment: @50_Seconds_Of_Coding Please check it the problem I have mentioned the LogCat

Comment: @SouravDasPlease check it the problem I have mentioned the LogCat

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Logcat

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lcit.lcitnewdemo, PID: 4372
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.lcit.lcitnewdemo/com.lcit.lcitnewdemo.SetActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to 
android.widget.Toolbar
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3356)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
at 
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks
(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at 
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at 
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar cannot 
    be cast to android.widget.Toolbar
    at com.lcit.lcitnewdemo.SetActivity.onCreate(SetActivity.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7973)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500) 
    at 
    android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.
    java:83) 
    at 
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks
    (TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute
    (TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
    (RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4372 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing your logcat....
So as I can see from logcat you imported your toolbar wrongly

***androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to
android.widget.Toolbar***

See above error specifically,
Now what you need to do is check your imports and change the line

***import android.widget.Toolbar***

to

***import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar***

Answer (score 0):

in xml file

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/yourID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

---

In java file

Import like this.

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```